# Как запустить файл с расширением .c ?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Консольное приложение на его основе создать или как-то еще, вариант "создать пустой проект  и скопировать код" не предлагать =) Среда VS 10

Comment: >  вариант "создать пустой проект и скопировать код" не предлагать

Можешь идти лесом. Как завести машину непользуясь бензином?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создай в VS проект Консольное приложение и добавь нужный тебе файл в этот проект.
Потом компилируй спокойно весь проект и будет тебе счастье.

Comment: ну видимо придется так и сделать, просто интересно было, можно ли это сделать как-то красиво

Comment: можно, если есть линукс с gcc ну или узнать ключи к VS компилятору. 
 
для gcc команда:  
gcc твойфаил.с -о твойфайлнавыходе  
для VS команда:    
cl твойфайл.с 'а здесь должны быть какие то ключи, которые я незнаю'

Answer (score 3):

Файл с расширением .c - скорее всего исходный код программы, написанной на C. Чтобы этот файл "запустить", его нужно сначала скомпилировать.

Comment: дак скомпилировать не могу) проекта как такового нету, через file->open->project не открыть, а через open->file скомпилировать не дает

Comment: Я точно не уверен, но полагаю, в VS тоже есть консольные компиляторы, которые позволяют компилировать одиночные файлы.

Answer (score 0):

Если не получается скомпилировать в VS, то попробуйте в какой нибудь из версий C++ Builder(помнится мне, что ему все равно что открывать проект или одиночный файл).

Comment: тоже не позволяет скомпилировать